# Ritual casting for a multiclass character

Tags: multi-classing, rituals, 13th-age

One of my players want to play a Druid / Wizard character. He needs Ritual Casting for both classes.

Does he have to take the talent once or does he have to take it twice, once for each class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### He doesn't have to take it at all.

Clerics and wizards are automatically ritual casters (*13th Age*, p. 192), and that's inherent to their training, not a talent. As a multiclass wizard/druid, you get it for free, presuming you're using the multiclass rules from *13 True Ways*.